# Seaborn kdeplot works in local - gives error in amazon sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, amazon-sagemaker

I am running the following straightforward code:

```
sns.kdeplot(data=subset_data['VaribleA'],fill=True,  color = "#FF0000" , linewidth=1, bw_method = 0.25)
```

When I run it on my local machine, I am able to run it without any issues.

But when I run it on an Amazon Sagemaker Jupyter Notebook, but installing and initializing all the same libraries, I get the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'fill'
```

Has anyone else faced this issue? Any recommendations on how to fix it?

Comment: are `sns.__version__` and `matplotlib.__version__` different between sagemaker vs local?